# Advice on code organization to deal with almost similar Requests but different models

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am developing an API using usual resource controllers, and I have some questions about the "right way" to do things. Obviously I know how to do it, but I am looking for the most appropriate/clean way to do it.

Let's say I have the following models and the corresponding resource controllers:

- Book / BookController (route: /api/books)
- Magazine / MagazineController (route: /api/magazines)

I need to make API endpoints to allow book publishers to push list of books or magazines (not one by one but many at once)

**First question**

What would be:

- The location of the method to handle these two endpoints. Should it be in the Resource controllers?
- The name of the method
- The route

What is the state-of-the-art for this?

**Second question**

I make the situation a bit more complex.

The two endpoints allowing book publishers to upload their books or magazines have both additional parameters that would be applied to all books or magazines.

The post data would contain the following parameters:

For books:

- books: [ list of books ] => [{title: "blabla", "autho": "toto"}, {...}]
- year
- category
- topics (comma separated topics)

For magazines:

- magazines: [ list of magazines ] => [{title: "blabla", "autho": "toto"}, {...}]
- year
- category
- topics (comma separated topics)

When books or magazines are stored, various controls are made and the magazine or book models are modified accordingly.

Keep it mind this is an example, we are not interested here to assess the models in themselves.

How to develop that cleanly? I am currently a bit frustrated because I deal with $request, without any intermediate formalized structure that would allow type-hinting and typed stuff. This leads also to a big method in my controller, it seems ugly.

I had a look on two things:

- Eloquent resources, which acts as an intermediate between models and JSON, but it seems to be mainly to query the database and display the results, not in the opposite way (Am I wrong?)
- Laravel DTO (through the Spatie Data module), but it seems overkill.

**Third question**

As several additional parameters and controls are common to these two endpoints, I want to avoid copy-paste of parts of the code. What would be the best way to do it?

Keep in mind that the question is not on the data-model itself, but to discuss what is the "state-of-the-art" to solve these requirements with concrete suggestions, including filenames, route names, directories, etc.

Also, if you can answer (even briefly) the questions in the order specified, it would help.

**Current situation**

I put currently a "storeAll" method (route: /api/books/store_all) in my resource controller (idem for magazines). The current methods are big and seems source of bugs.

Both methods (for books and magazines) have common codes/checks that are duplicated.

Many thanks